# Conversion error when returning an Iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm experimenting with the "find" function. I can't seem to be able to return
the iterator.

```
template<typename T>                                                                                                  
typename T::iterator do_find(const T &v, int f)                                                                       
{                                                                                                                     
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), f);                                                                           
}
```

And here is my main :

```
int main()                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                     
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6};                                                                      
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;                                                                                
    it = do_find(v, 3);                                                                                           
    return 0;                                                                                                     
}
```

When I compile I get the following error :

```
error: impossible de convertir
« std::find<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >, int>((& v)->std::vector<int>::begin(), (& v)->std::vector<int>::end(), f) » de « __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> > » vers « std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >} »
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v` is declared as `const`, then for `std::vector`, both [`v.begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) and [`v.end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) return `std::vector::const_iterator`, then the return type of `find` will be `std::vector::const_iterator` too; it can't be converted to `std::vector::iterator` implicitly.

You can change the return type, e.g.

```
template<typename T>                                                                                                  
typename T::const_iterator do_find(const T &v, int f)                                                                       
{                                                                                                                     
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), f);                                                                           
}
```

or just

```
template<typename T>                                                                                                  
auto do_find(const T &v, int f)                                                                       
{                                                                                                                     
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), f);                                                                           
}
```

then

```
auto it = do_find(v, 3);
```

If you want to modify the element through the returned iterator, then you should declare the parameter `v` to be non-const.

```
template<typename T>                                                                                                  
auto do_find(T &v, int f)                                                                       
{                                                                                                                     
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), f);                                                                           
}
```

Note that with `auto`, the above `do_find` will return `iterator` if you pass a non-const `vector`, and return `const_iterator` if you pass a const `vector`.

Comment: Oh, that's why. Tanks !

Answer (score 1):

`v` is `const`; meaning that `std::find` will return a `T::const_iterator`.  You're attempting to return a `T::iterator`; and the compiler can't convert from `const` to non-const.

The fix is to either return the `const_iterator` or to make `v` non-const.  Depending on exactly what you want to do with the iterator.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have passed T as a const in the first place. Thanks for helping

Comment: *"I shouldn't have passed T as a const in the first place."* - If you don't modify the vector in `do_find`, and the name strongly implies that you don't, then no, you **should** pass it as `const`! Use the `const_iterator` / `auto` solutions.

Comment: You could easily overload your function to have both `T::iterator find(T v)` and `T::const_iterator find(const T v)`; then you support all cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the function the container is declared as a constant container

```
template <typename T>
typename T::iterator do_find(const T &v, int f);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the member functions `begin` and `end` of this container return objects of the type `typename T::const_iterator` that can not be implicitly converted to the type.`typename T::iterator`.

Also it is not clear why the second parameter has the type `int` instead of the type `typename T::value_type`.

There is a magic word `auto` in C++ that can simplify the function declaration and using its return value.

The function can be defined the following way

```
template <typename T>        
auto do_find( const T &v, typename T::value_type value ){                                                                                                                     
    return std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), value );           
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>        
auto do_find( const T &v, typename T::value_type value ){                                                                                                                     
    return std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), value );           
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6 };

    auto it = do_find(v, 3);  

    if ( it != v.end() )
    {
        std::cout << *it << " is found at position "
                  << std::distance( v.cbegin(), it ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3 is found at position 2
```